# Can I add an additional hard disk to the Medion ERAZER P7643 MD99838?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I’m looking to buy a new laptop. I found the Medion Erazer P7643 (MD 99730) which has two HDs (a 256 GB SSD and a 1 TB HD).

There is another much cheaper model, the Medion Erazer P7643 (MD 99838), which comes with *only* the SSD. However, I’m having difficulty finding out whether the laptop still has a slot for another HD.

Is it possible to add another internal HD to the MD 99838?

Comment: Provide us the hardware specifications (English) for both since these are very regional products.